# What is the missing operator in my command?

Tags: database, vb.net

My program works perfectly, but now the only problem is that the when the database has been updated, an alert box will appear saying:

**Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'ID='.**

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim choice As String
    choice = MsgBox("Do you really want to delete?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
    If choice = vbYes Then
        cnn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Database.accdb")
        Dim str As String = ("DELETE FROM TableName WHERE ID= " & ComboBox1.Text & "")
        command = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(str, cnn)
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(command)
        cnn.Open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Form1.Timer1.Enabled = True
        clearfields()
        Form1.Timer1.Enabled = False
        Me.Close()
    End If

    cnn.Close()

End Sub
```

It says that the error is located here: (ID is an Autonumber.)

```
Dim str As String = ("DELETE FROM TableName WHERE ID= " & ComboBox1.Text & "")
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i

Comment: @OneFineDay Hi, I tried it, but now it shows another error: "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." What could be the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix my own problem, what I did is I changed my ID to text, so I will not have problems in the command.

```
Dim str As String = ("DELETE FROM TableName WHERE ID= " & ComboBox1.Text & "")
```

And then I had a problem in the timer, it won't start. I retyped the code and fixed some mistakes. Now my program runs perfectly and smoothly! Thank you all for your help, I really appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim str As String = ("DELETE FROM TableName WHERE ID= '" & ComboBox1.Text & "'")
```

You need single quotes for the value

Comment: I tried it, but now it shows another error: "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." What could be the reason?

Comment: can you try commenting this line                                        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(command)

Comment: Try changing combobox1.text to CInt(ComboBox1.Text)

Comment: It says still the error Data Type. What I did is I removed the single quotes and did the CInt(combobox1.text). Yes the Data Type Error does not show now, but the Syntax Error (missing operator) shows again.

Comment: Woahh! I realized that this error is not caused by the command!

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't encapsulate string assignments in parentheses, and you must surround the query text in quotes.

```
Dim str As String = "DELETE FROM TableName WHERE ID= '" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"
```

Be careful.  Your code opens you up to SQL Injection queries.  Whatever is in ComboBox1.Text will be parsed as a SQL Command. If the ComboBox ever recieves text from a user, you must sanitize the input. Imagine how much fun you'd have if the user managed to put this text in your textbox

```
' OR 1=1 OR 'a' =';
```

So the database would process the command

```
DELETE FROM TableName WHERE ID= '' OR 1=1 OR 'a' =''
```

That command will delete all of your records.